# Facebook LIVE API Integration in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, live-streaming, facebook-live-api, videocore

I want to create an iOS App in which user will login via Facebook and go live and it should show live on Facebook.

I started with the following demo :

https://github.com/hansemannn/facebook-live-ios/

For live streaming it is using `Video Core` library. I have successfully build the project.

The problem is when I call start streaming function this `Video Core Delegate` is called :

```
public func connectionStatusChanged(_ sessionState: VCSessionState) {
    if sessionState == .started {
        self.isStreaming = true
    } else if sessionState == .ended || sessionState == .error {
        self.isStreaming = false
    }
```

}

Here, I am always getting the session state as .starting and then .ends. It should be .started for going Live.

**NOTE:** I am using Facebook user with all permissions.

Comment: you mean as if your video is starting and then ending instantly?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If it will go to started then only streaming will begin

Comment: have you configured FB id correctly?

Comment: Yes everything is perfect problem is with `VideoCore` streaming SDK

Comment: Hi, Did you solve your problem? I'm also trying same thing in my iOS app.